# Will an empty SQLite cursor return true for isBeforeFirst, isAfterLast, both, or neither?

Tags: android, sqlite

It's a pretty straightforward question. I'm hoping the answer is "both", but I'm worried it's neither. I've scrutinized the Android developer docs for [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) and [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html), but can't find any definitive answer to this question.

The case I'm asking about is where I get a cursor, call `moveToFirst`, then loop until `isAfterLast` returns true. It would be really convenient for a pattern I'm coding a few times if that would just work and execute the loop 0 times if the cursor has 0 records.

Or do I need to explicitly test for an empty cursor first?

**EDIT:** Some of the responses indicate that people aren't quite getting what I'm asking. Basically, I would like to write this:

```
cursor = myDb.query(...)
cursor.moveToFirst()
while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
    processRow(...)
}
```

But I'm not 100% certain that I can. `isAfterLast` can't return anything *useful* but true for this case, but that doesn't mean it actually does return true for an empty query. The docs don't seem to specify what the return value of most of the cursor methods are if the cursor is empty (the Android docs seem to be unspecific on a lot of corner cases, actually), other than `getCount`. So I'm worried that I need to do this:

```
cursor = myDb.query(...)
if (cusror.getCount() > 0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst()
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        processRow(...)
    }
}
```

Which is messier and logically redundant. Bear in mind that in the real implementation there's more code, and this is spread across multiple methods. And one of the answers is now suggesting that I need to check the cursor for `null` as well, which is completely undocumented...

I simply want to know whether anyone else knows the actual behaviour of `isAfterLast` when called on an empty cursor.

Comment: why don't you call cursor.getCount() to know whether cursor have items or not.

Comment: Try to find whether cursor is empty or not for this if(Cursor != null) then you can also check the count of cursor like Cursor.getCount(). If no record then it returns 0.

Comment: @Ilango @user37 I know how to check whether a cursor has items or not, the question is whether I can **avoid** this check. I have some code that needs to run once for each row of a query's results, and if there are 0 results then I want to execute my code 0 times i.e. do nothing. Given that I have `while(!cursor.isAfterLast())` it would be much cleaner not to have to wrap that whole thing in an if block, if `isAfterLast` is going to return true for an empty cursor anyway.

Comment: @Ben i can't get understand your question. And i can't understand exactly what you need?

Comment: @Ilango I've added more explanation to my question, including code examples.

Comment: instead of looping your cursor with condition  while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        processRow(...)
    }  why don't you try with   while (!cursor.moveToNext()) {
        processRow(...)
    }

Comment: @Ilango Ah, didn't realise that returned a bool. Good advice. The docs still don't specify what happens if you call that on an empty cursor though, so same question. I guess it could hardly return `true`, so I can just try it and see if I get a "cursor is empty" exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't use `isAfterLast`. I use the following pattern to read the query result.

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = new DbHelper().getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "SELECT ...";
    String[] args = ...;
    Cursor cs = db.rawQuery(sql, args);
    while (cs.moveToNext()) {
        // cs.getXxx(0), cs.getXxx(1)
    }
    cs.close();
    db.close();
```

`DbHelper` is a class that I extend from `SQLiteOpenHelper`

Comment: Do you know that this works (i.e. just skips over the loop body with no exceptions) when the query returned 0 rows?

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'm accepting this answer (even though an answer to my original question is still what I really want, as `isAfterLast`/`isBeforeFirst` allow me to decouple advancing to the next row from checking for exhaustion if I need to).

Comment: But cursor.getXXX() won't return an exception if there's no row to read?

Comment: @Ben: I agree that your actual question remains unanswered. So did you ever find out whether `isBeforeFirst()` returning `false` is a reliable way of checking for an empty cursor?

Answer (score 7):

When the cursor is empty,

cursor.moveToFirst() returns false
cursor.isBeforeFirst() returns true
cursor.isAfterLast() returns true

So yes, the first code snippet you posted will work fine on an empty cursor.